# (Windows) Delete JetBrains IDE File Type Name

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I used to have 4 JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, GoLand, PyCharm, and CLion. However I deleted them because they were not very light weight and I discovered the greatness of Neovim.

However, whenever I open my file explorer and open a folder with some code, I would see the file name (i.e. `main.go`) and under the File Type section, it would say JetBrains (IDE name)

For example;

```
File Name --------------- File Type

main.go   --------------- JetBrains GoLand File
```

Also, when I right-click the file, it still shows the "Open With (a JetBrains IDE)" despite them being deleted.

Those two problems are occurring with all 4 JetBrains IDEs I used to have (PyCharm, CLion, GoLand, IntelliJ)

My end goal:

- When right clicking a file, I don't want the option to open it in a JetBrains IDE (because the IDEs are deleted)
- `.go` / `.java` / `.py` (etc) files shouldn't say JetBrains (IDE name) under the File Type section

EDIT: I attached 1 image highlighting what I want to get rid of

[the file type of `.go` files should say Go Source File (or whatever the original name used to be) and the same for the other files modified by JetBrains (`.py` `.c` `.cpp` `.hpp` `.h` `.hxx` `.cxx` `.java`] \ also: there shouldnt be an option to open the files using the IDEs (because theyre deleted) Goal:
 [image: Goal Image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Are you asking how to clear the file association?  What extensions are we talking about?

Comment: Yeah if you have discord i can show you pictures to clearly describe my goal